# reading of span class data in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a tag like this I presume this is in child class... I tried to click the button with "details" text... I am getting no element found error.

```html
span _ngcontent-tbi-c3="" class="ng-star-inserted">Details</span
```

My python code:-

```
a = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "//span[text()='Details']") 
self.click(a) 
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Details']"))).click() -----tried this approach also how do we solve it..
```

Comment: Could u provide the link of the website?

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Are you sure that you can use `By.LINK_TEXT`? That "link" seems to be not a link (`<a ...>`) but just a `span` inside many `div`s...

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your photo, I believe that we can isolate our `xpath` with the following

```
# xpath to find the button for the span
//div[@class='container-wrapper']//div[@class='tab-header']//mat-tab-group[contains(@class, 'mat-tab-group')]//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content']//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..
```

The `/../..` tells `selenium` to traverse / move back 2 levels. This will bring you to the `div cdkmonitorelementfocus` element that has the `tabindex` of -1. In my presumption, I believe that tabindex -1 means that the tab is not selected. ( You might have to clarify this with your developer )

From this assumption, you can have `selenium` click on your tab

```
# our xpath
xpath_text = //div[@class='container-wrapper']//div[@class='tab-header']//mat-tab-group[contains(@class, 'mat-tab-group')]//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content']//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..

# clicks our web element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()
```

I would make sure that you can open your Google Chrome Developer Tools ( F12 ), go to the Elements Tab, press `CTRL + F` ( the universal "Find" feature ) and paste the `xpath` inside of the Find Textbox that displays at the bottom. If the result is `1 of 1`, then you are good. If the result is something similar to `1 of 2` or `1 of 4`, then you should wrap your `xpath` and get the first element

This is the `xpath` for the `label level` clicking

```
# xpath - label level
//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/..

# xpath - click label level
xpath_text = "//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/.."
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()


# xpath - label level - wrapped
(//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/..)[1]

# xpath - click label level - wrapped
xpath_text = "(//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/..)[1]"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()
```

This is the `xpath` for the `cdkmonitorelementfocus` level

```
# xpath - cdkmonitorelementfocus level
//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..

# xpath - click cdkmonitorelementfocus level
xpath_text = "//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../.."
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()


# xpath - cdkmonitorelementfocus level - wrapped
(//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..)[1]

# xpath - cdkmonitorelementfocus label level - wrapped
xpath_text = "(//mat-tab-header[@class='mat-tab-header']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@cdkmonitorelementfocus]//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..)[1]"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()
```

Comment: /html/body/app-root/div/div/div/app-dashboard-web/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/mat-tab-group/mat-tab-header/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span  This was the full xpath hence i went a step up and written the code as self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div//span[contains(., 'Details')]/..").click() still i am getting error as no such element or element not found

Comment: element_to_double_click = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content']//span[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(text(),'Details')]")
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.click(element_to_double_click)
        # perform the operation on the element
        actions.perform() ****Tried the same with actions also still not working*** as a first assumption i thought my xpath is wrong when i copy pasted that in the inspect page i could see it highligted to the required class

Comment: Hmm .... is it possible to add a screenshot of the HTML Source? Because without the source, it can be difficult to see why you are not getting your element. Something that you could use is: `element = WebDriverWait(your_driver_here, 10).until( expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located( locator = (By.XPATH, "xpath here"))`

Comment: i have attached a screenshot at the top do let me know how to solve it..

Comment: @swaroopgarlapati - Updated my answer

Comment: i checked with the updated code.. still i am facing the issue as unable to locate element.. when i searched with x path i got the result as 1 0f 1 I have used the following code...    xpath_text = //div[@class='container-wrapper']//div[@class='tab-header']//mat-tab-group[contains(@class, 'mat-tab-group')]//div[@class='mat-tab-label-container']//div[@class='mat-tab-labels']//div[@class='mat-tab-label-content']//span[contains(., 'Details')]/../..

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_text).click()

Comment: Try the wrapped version

Comment: @swaroopgarlapati - I updated the answer. I added the cdkmonitorelementfocus element and the label element. ( I think you should try the wrapped version )

Comment: THanks for the answer the original issue was due to iframes when i used switch to frame the issue got resolved thank you once again

Comment: @swaroopgarlapati - No problem. I didn't see the iFrame; otherwise, this would have been a good step to go into. I'm glad that you were able to figure out your issue